Node Express Plantilla EJS no logro renderizar una ruta



Mauricio Contreras contesto esta pregunta correctamente  ..Si la ruta /  es la ultima declarada asi puedo acceder a la ruta pagina/administar sin problemas...
*

El problema es que el link desde la pagina principal pagina.ejs .Si uso "/" me muestra la pagina de logeo que es la que necesito !!
Pero si uso"/administrar" como ruta para la pagina.ejs da error 404 por lo cual elimino esa ruta y si consigo ir entonces dede pagin.ejs a pagina de logeo ..Pero no entiendo porque no funciona la ruta administar ya que si escribo directamente !!! en Chrome localhost:3000/pagina/administrar si me muestra la pagina de logeo



router.get('/administrar', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('index', { title: 'Agencia', session : req.session });
  });





// app.js

-----
---
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var turistasRouter= require('./routes/turistas');
var paginaRouter=require ('./routes/pagina');

app.use('/turistas',turistasRouter);
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/pagina',paginaRouter);

----
----
carpeta routes contiene a --> index.js ;pagina.js;turistas,js

index.js
---
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Agencia', session : req.session });
});
---
---
 turistas.js
 router.get('/',function(req, res, next) {    
    const sessionData = req.session;
   console.log("sessionData:",sessionData );
   if(sessionData.user_id ==1){
    dbConn.query('SELECT * FROM agencia.turista ORDER BY id desc',function(err,rows)     {
        if(err) {
            req.flash('error', err);
            // render to views/turistas/index.ejs
            res.render('turistas',{data:''});   
        } else {
            // render en  views/turistas/index.ejs
            res.render('turistas',{data:rows});
        }
    
    });
  } else{
   
   
    console.log("Debes Logearte");
    res.render('index', { title: 'Debes Logearte', session : req.session });
  }
   
});
 
 -------
 pagina.js
 --------
 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('pagina',{});
  });

-------

/*carpeta views contiene a --->index.ejs  verifica si el usuario se logeo 
si asi es ve listado de pasajeros si no es asi se muestra formulario de logeo; pagina.ejs es la pagina que ve el publico y tiene un enlace a administrar que es el que muestro en HTML  
dentro de viws carpeta turistas contiene --> otra index.ejs la cual muestra a los turistas y operaciones crud 
*/
 
--------
-----
<li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/">
              <h4> Administrar</h4>
            </a>
</li>



-----




Mueve la declaración de rutas, de tal forma que / sea la última ruta declarada por tus app.use, comenta el resultado.

Gracias ahora con tu indicación funciona  para esta ruta href="pagina/administrar">--cual es el motivo de ese comportamiento? Gracias

por favor si podes responde como respuesta así la doy como valida y cierro la pregunta
